# How do i get the playing song details(title - artist- album.. etc) in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash

[image]

When i play a song in ubuntu whether from banshee or spotify or any other music player, the song shows up in the sound indicator menu.
How can i get the details of the playing song from the indicator using bash or command line?

**Edit:**

- The played song can be an mp3 file, online stream or radio.
- I need to get the data from the indicator regardless of the music
  player that is playing the song (or any other method that doesn't 
  involve using the music player app).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Should I cite manpage `banshee(1)`?

```
   --query-position
          Print player position in currently playing track

   --query-uri
          Print URI of current track

   --query-artist
          Print artist name of current track

   --query-album
          Print album title of current track

   --query-title
          Print title of current track

   --query-duration
          Print duration of current track

   --query-track-number
          Print track number of current track

   --query-track-count
          Print album track count for current track

   --query-disc
          Print disc number of current track

   --query-year
          Print year of release of current track

   --query-rating
          Print user rating of current track
```

Comment: can i not get the data from the sound indicator? or do i have to use the music player's library or wharever?

Comment: @razzak `$ banshee --query-title`. Or did you mean ‘every’ by ‘any’ in “banshee or spotify or any other music player”?

Comment: i meant like regardless of what music player im using how do i get the metadata of the playing song that shows up in the indicator? if it's not possible how do i do that using spotify

Answer (score 0):

Install the `id3v2` package -- man page:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/id3v2.1.html

Comment: the playing song is not necessarily an mp3 file, it could be an online stream or a radio station

Comment: I imagine the answer will be app-specific.